# RemoveDuplicates gives 1004 error

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I want to remove duplicates from my selection, but this line gives me a 1004 error:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B3", Range("B3").End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlNo
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your line into:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(range("B3"), Range("B3").End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
```

or,if you really have 2 columns into:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(range("B3"), Range("C3").End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlNo
```

Comment: Oh damn I'm stupid ! Thanks a lot, I thought Columns was the destination Column index where the data would be copied.

Comment: OMG, it's 2022 and thank you so much for this answer!